# Java Compare complex objects excluding some fields for JUnit

Tags: java, object, junit, comparison

I tried the Unitils tool which is really great, but doesn't provide you an option for excluding fields. The only way by doing this is to set `null` the objects and enable the `IGNORE_DEFAULTS` flag, but in my case, it's not helpful, since I've got some ids autogenerated by the system. So if I could just add the id to an exclude list it would be perfect.

I also tried Mockito's `ReflectionEquals` but it was not helpful, since I need a field-to-field comparison.

Is there something else helpful? I have been searching for hours without success.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Side note: if you end up writing your own "reflection based" field checker ... consider using **assertThat** and writing your own custom matchers for it. That might at least allow you to make use of the superior features of **assertThat**.

Answer (score 27):

You could solve your problem by using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). It can do [field-by-field recursive comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison) with options to [ignore fields](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-fields) by name, regex or type.

```
assertThat(sherlock)
  .usingRecursiveComparison()
  .ignoringFields("name", "home.address.street")
  .isEqualTo(moriarty);
```

Comment: Pure gold, thank you

Answer (score -1):

We use our own approach in groovy (similar to [Frank Neblung's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774054/frank-neblung) answer ) where we convert an object to a formated Json string using an ObjectMapper and a filterList for the attributes. This is pretty handy for testing but has also some downsides like the loss of type information.

```
// interface of the conversion
String nice(Object o, String... filterList) { ... }

// test calls
assertEquals(nice(actual, ["-unusedAttribute", "-unusedAttribute2"]), nice(expected, ["-unusedAttribute", "-unusedAttribute2"]))
assertEquals(nice(actual, ["+usedAttibute", "+usedAttibute2"]), nice(expected, ["+usedAttibute", "+usedAttibute2"]))

// test calls using the spock framework
nice(actual, ["-unusedAttribute", "-unusedAttribute2"]) == nice(expected, ["-unusedAttribute", "-unusedAttribute2"])
nice(actual, ["+usedAttibute", "+usedAttibute2"]) == nice(expected, ["+usedAttibute", "+usedAttibute2"])
```

Answer (score -2):

It wouldn't be that hard to roll your own using java reflection, if you don't like the capabilities of the ones you're finding.

Comment: Saying "do it yourself if you don't like what you've got so far"  is not in any way helping the OP solve the problem

Comment: 5 years ago... I find if I spend more than about a half hour searching for a tool that will do what I want, then having someone say, "Maybe you can roll your own with <insert language feature>" can be a useful nudge. He spent hours searching and isn't satisfied. He also never gave a "best answer" green checkbox to the suggestion of AssertJ. Maybe someone nudging java reflection at him was useful or not. Maybe for other people who see this answer, a nudge at reflection may be enough to look and consider. Or maybe not.